# When is $\int |f| =\int f$

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find a similar thread.

I'm currently trying to prove a fact regarding the total variation of a function and the integral of it's derivative.

If $f$ is non-decreasing is it true that $\int^b_a |f|=\int^b_a f$?

Answer (score 2):

No, take for example $f(x)=x$ and $a=-2$ and $b=-1$. Nevertheless, your statement holds whenever $f\geq 0$.

Comment: Note also that it is not true that $\int |f| = | \int f |$ by taking $a = -2$ and $b = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=x$, $a=-1$, $b=1$.

In general, call $f^+=\max\{f,0\}$ and $f^-=\max\{-f,0\}$. In the language of Lebesgue integration (id est, if we discuss measurable functions such that either $\int \lvert f\rvert<\infty$ or at least one of $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ is finite), notice that these are non-negative functions and that $$\lvert f\rvert=f^++f^-\\ f=f^+-f^-\\ \int \lvert f\rvert=\int f^++\int f^-\\ \int f=\int f^+-\int f^-$$

And therefore $\int \lvert f\rvert=\int f$ if and only if either $\int f^+=\infty$ and $\int f^-<\infty$ or $\int f^-=0$. Non-negativity of $f^-$ implies that the second case is equivalent to $f$ being non-negative almost everywhere.

With similar argument, $\int \lvert f\rvert=\lvert\int f\rvert$ if and only if either $f$ has almost everywhere the same sign, or one of $\int f^\pm$ is infinite and the other is finite.

Comment: "$\int f^+=\infty$ and $\int f^-<\infty$" There are cases when they are both infinite. Like $f(x)=\sin(x)+\frac12$ integrated over the whole number line. I think it's better to just say "$\int f=\infty$". Same issue for the $|\int f|$ case.

Comment: @Arthur In that case, then I would say that by all means $\int\lvert f\rvert=\int f$ is false and $(\int f^-<\infty\land \int f^+=\infty)\lor \int f^-=0$ is false as well, so I don't see a problem. The only problem arises if the guy tries to adapt this machinery to the syntactically similar language of indefinite Riemann integrals, where the scope of the discussion must be amended. I've addressed such issue by adding a premise.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int |f| = \int f \Longleftrightarrow \int(|f|-f) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow f=|f|~~a.e. \Longleftrightarrow f \geq 0 ~~a.e. $$